# Error Message : InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting following error while trying to update the entity in google cloud datastore:

```
InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind.
    at keyToKeyProto (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/src/entity.js:696:11)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DatastoreRequest.createReadStream (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/src/request.js:226:23)
    at DatastoreRequest.get (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/src/request.js:461:8)
    at /Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:681:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Datastore.wrapper [as get] (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:662:20)
    at fetchEntity (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/gstore-node/lib/model.js:204:36)
    at Function.get (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/gstore-node/lib/model.js:174:16)
    at Promise (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/gstore-node/lib/utils.js:39:35)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.wrapper (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/node_modules/gstore-node/lib/utils.js:27:16)
    at resolve (/Volumes/Drive B/dev/zapi/graphql/mutations/user/linkConsult.js:101:44)
```

I don't know why is this coming for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A (kind, ID/name) pair used to construct a key path. A kind matching regex __.*__ is reserved/read-only. Cannot be "".[Learn more](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you trying to access key and key is not available when no data available, it gives the error

> "Error Message : InvalidKey: A key should contain at least a kind"

To avoid this error first make sure that [datastrore.KEY] is available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this answer with a little more detail. Here are some other helpful points to investigate if you run into this error when using the datastore.save method. The entity needs the correct key property like the example below.

```
// remember to use the key method on the google data store instance
const entity = {
  key: dataStore.key('Name of your Kind') // this is Kind property you see on the GCP dashboard,
  data: {
    example: 'this is an example',
    ...
  }
};

// then save the entity
const dbResult = await dataStore.save(entity)
```